# Map Visual Studio MacOS super key from cmd -> ctrl

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm not a big fan of the cmd super key on macOS positioning so would like to map to ctrl for ease of use across multi-platform on. I can see a way to modify key bindings one by one. I'm looking for an option to do the whole lot in one go.

Comment: Not great but you could  `Open Default Keyboard Shortcuts` (from the Command Palette), copy all, paste into your keybindings.json and then find/replace cmd->ctrl.

Comment: I did see this as a potential option earlier. AS you say though, not ideal. Weird that they haven't made the super key more easily interchangeable.